# How can i save and playback a android TTS output with already recorded audio file(like merging two audio) in a single line?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Am trying an android app,which has few text fields.

For Example,  your name is............ and your age is ..........., after getting text input from user,while on some click (button), it should playback like YOUR NAME IS RAJ and YOUR AGE IS 23 in a single line.

Where the part "YOUR NAME IS"  (recorded audio file from drawables) and "RAJ" audio part is android text to speech output file (After saving ).
**Is it possible to merge this two  audio files and playback ??**

please help if there is any way to achieve this??

Comment: use all the audio into string then merge the string with your field string then use tts as output... for ex:- String a="YOUR NAME IS" then String b="Pragadees" then string c=a+b; then use TTS for c...